# What amperage Android sends to jack 3.5?

Tags: voltage, current, amperage, android

I want to use signal of Android's jack 3.5 as key for my circuit.
For this reason I want to know amperage and voltage which Android can send to this port

Comment: what is `jack 3.5`?  .... Android is software. It is an operating system that is used on smart phones and other devices. I do not think that it has a "jack".

Comment: What do you mean "as key" for your circuit? As a signal to trigger some action, or something else?

Comment: @jsotola jack 3.5 is an audio connector. Almost every Android device has this connector. And OS converts audio files to bits and sends this bits through jack

Comment: @Ali_Chen yes, as trigger. I want to send impulse from android to circuit using this port

Comment: You seem to be mistaken about bits, the internal IC converts bits into AC analog waveforms. But you can make a small rectifier-detector for the AC signal, and trigger whatever you want, see typical signal specs from Transistor. I frequently used this sound-triggering technique in Windows, when debugging system USB issues.

Comment: @V.Govorov, now i know what you mean .... it is a `3.5mm audio connector jack` ... not jack 3.5 .... please use correct terminology when asking questions

Answer (score 0):

The jack on a mobile phone, including phones running the Android operating system, is designed to output audio at signal levels sufficient to drive headphones or the line input to an amplifier. On [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec) the specifications are given that the minimum load on the audio out is 16 Ω.

The output voltage will be about 1 V and is limited to about 150 mW. The amplifier output is usually AC coupled (there is a capacitor in series with the output) and will not give a DC output.

> For this reason I want to know amperage and voltage which Android can send to this port.

You are confused about what Android is. Android is the software operating system that runs on the phone hardware. The hardware is what outputs the audio.

Comment: Just an FYI. My Galaxy S8 specsheet states it has 2 watts RMS per channel for ear-buds, and 120 dB dynamic range if 24 bit audio or 130 bit dynamic range if 32 bit audio is used.

Comment: That sounds dangerous!

Comment: It can be on recordings made since about 2012. I had never heard of 32 bit audio until I heard it. Perfect silence, just like 24 bit, then Celine Dion blasting your ear drums with absolutely clear sound. Profound deep bass with AKG ear-buds. Comes with the phone.

Comment: 2W? that's a good way to blow out your eardrums

Comment: @laptop2d, it depends on rated efficiency of acoustic driver. As I used to say in deep past, "my stove says it is 2 kW, why my sound is so weak when I connect it to audio amplifier?" :-)

Comment: "2W? that's a good way to blow out your eardrums" – laptop2d Especially if listening to Celine Dion.